# AppCompat v21 PopupMenu style

Tags: android, styles, android-appcompat, popupmenu

I'm implementing a custom PopupMenu in my app and faced a difficulty styling it.

PopupMenu is created as:

```
    public DropDownMenu(Context context, Button button, int menuId,
                        OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
        mButton = button;
        mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, mButton);
        mMenu = mPopupMenu.getMenu();
        mPopupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(menuId, mMenu);
        mPopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPopupMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }

public DropDownMenu addDropDownMenu(Button button, int menuId) {
    DropDownMenu menu = new DropDownMenu(mContext, button, menuId, this);
    mMenus.add(menu);
    return menu;
}
```

in styles.xml I set:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupMenu.MenuItemText.Large</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/PopupMenu.MenuItemText.Small</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/anybill_blue</item>
</style>
```

I tried applying various styles and attributes, but no matter what I do I always see this:
[image]

How to get rid of those ridiculous incorrect layout padding? I guess it's all about I'm missing some important style attribute.

Not sure if it matters, but style worked fine when I used it without AppCompat lib in API 19 code.

UPDATE: if I use android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu, then style is as above. If I use android.widget.PopupMenu, then no styles applied at all - it's always white background and black text, but displayed correctly

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have it also..

Comment: Unfortunately not.I re-designed UI to get rid of popup menu

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add this to your popupstyle:

```
<item name="android:popupElevation">0dp</item>
```